# Creating an instance of generic class, how to easily set the type to the calling class

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have a generic class `LoggerHelper<T>`. There are properties in many different classes in the application, whose values are to be set to instances of `LoggerHelper`. In the constructors of these classes, this property will be set. For example:

```
public class Importer
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public Importer()
    {  
        this._logger = new LoggerHelper<Importer>();
    }
}
```

How can I avoid specifying the type each time? Is there are suitable pattern for this?

Comment: You could use reflection to create the object, but that's a bit nasty. Alternatively, make `Importer` inherit from a base class that does this for you (`class Importer : BaseClass<Importer>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a factory method, thus a type could be inferred by the compiler.

---

#### Static method

```
public static class LoggerHelperFactory
{
    public static LoggerHelper<T> Create<T>(T instance)
    {
        return new LoggerHelper<T>();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
_logger = LoggerHelperFactory.Create(this);
```

---

#### Extension method

```
public static class LoggerHelperFactoryExtensions
{
    public static LoggerHelper<T> CreateLogger<T>(this T instance)
    {
        return new LoggerHelper<T>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
_logger = this.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: You could even make this an extension method for added brevity and to remove the need to explicitly pass any parameters.

Comment: While this works, all you're really doing is moving the "problem" to a different place.

Comment: @rodit How could this be implemented as an extension method? `LoggerHelper` is already generic, so you would need to specify the type when calling the extension.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay changing the method signature to this would work: `public static LoggerHelper<T> Create<T>(this T instance)` and then calling `this.Create()` (or just `Create()`) from any object would give you the LoggerHelper instance.

Comment: @rodit Ah yes; that's a good solution. Probably better to call the method `CreateLogger` though.